# Django how to save time to the forms?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am having a calender with available time slots using jquery. I want that datetime to save when user clicks on the appointment datetime available. After that redirect to booking form that date time save to my form datetimefield in booking form.

For example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xx4GS/258/

I am having same calendar and time in my page as I shared the link. I want this date time to save to my booking form datetimefield. If user clicks  `1/7/2018 08:00` it redirects to my form and saves to date time field.

**My Model**

```
class Booking(models.Model):  
    booking_name = models.CharField(max_length=240, null=False)  
    customer_name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_customers' )
    book_car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book_car')
    booking_start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)
    booking_end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True) 
    rental_price = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    times_pick = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):  
        return self.booking_name  
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("buggy_app:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

**Views .py**

```py
class BookingView(FormView):  
    template_name = 'buggy_app/booking.html'  
    form_class = BookingForm  
    models = Booking
    def form_valid(self, form):  
        form.save()
        return super(BookingView, self).form_valid(form)
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): # kwargs['car'] is the car booking now!  
        try:  
            kwargs['car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET.get('car', '')) 
        except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):  
            kwargs['car'] = None return super(BookingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)  
    def get_initial(self): 
        initial = super(BookingView, self).get_initial()  
        if 'car' in self.request.GET:   
            try: 
                initial['book_car'] = Car.objects.get(id=self.request.GET['car'])  
            except (Car.DoesNotExist, ValueError):  
                pass return initial
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Timestampmodel or models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) in model field.

Comment: I want user to select from available slot

Comment: And from slot the time user select save to the car booking form